# Добавить в urls в path ещё view

Tags: python, django

[image: В "статьи" я добавил, но в "Книги" и "развития"-нет[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZyzX.png)

Для "статьи" я так добавлял

Views*

```
def home(request):
data = {
    'news': News.objects.all(),
}
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)
```

HTMl*

```
{% for post in news %}
....

{% endfor %}
```

urls*

```
path('', views.ShowNewsView.as_view(), name='blog-home')
```

**Для books сделал всё тоже самое, но упёрся в urls надо вставить по одному адресу только один view**

views*

```
def block(request):
data = {
    'books': Book.objects.all(),
}
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)
```

HTML*

```
{% for post in books %}
....

{% endfor %}
```

Пытался и так

```
path('', views.ShowNewsView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('', views.block, name='block'),
```

И так

```
path('', views.ShowNewsView.as_view() and views.block, name='blog-home'),
```

Comment: Если вам действительно нужно сделать несколько разделов по одному адресу, могу предложить два варианта: 1. `Передавать в рендер контекст для всех вкладок сразу, а между самими вкладками переключаться через JS`. 2. `Кнопки перехода по вкладкам сложить в <form></form> с POST-методом, и в зависимости от POST-запроса выдавать рендер нужной страницы`. Первый вариант будет дольше грузиться, но быстрее переход между вкладками, второй - с точностью до наоборот. В любом случае, представление на все вкладки будет только одно. Вопрос в том, будут ли выдаваться все элементы сразу, или при каждом обращении

Answer (score 0):

Если прямо ответить на ваш вопрос, то "Добавить в urls в path ещё view" нельзя. Нужно делать так как описал вам в комментарии [Евгений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361777/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]